# Log level - Console and Messages.logs

Tags: logging, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

Can anyone please help to configure messages.logs and console.logs in worklight server through server.xml in liberty.

Thanks
Deepesh

Comment: Did you try to follow the Liberty documentation? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html

Comment: Yes i have seen this, but from where can we enable disable messages.logs and console.logs in liberty profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not Worklight log files. These belong to Liberty.
Per the [Liberty user documenation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-16-0-0)...

For console.log, set it like so: `com.ibm.ws.logging.console.log.level=OFF`.

I guess it may be the same for messages.log. But why would you turn off logging?
Change the logging level to the desired one.

Comment: Hi Idan, I need to turn off logging to some level in productio but just keep the error to be turned on, That would help me see all the errors happening on worklight level, Is that possible please suggest. Really appreciate your help on this one.

Comment: The documentation provides a list of log levels.